# inserting values into a map using a map pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a map pointer and I am trying to add values to it like so.

```
map<int, vector<int>> *m;
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(100);
(*m)[0] = v
```

The above code is giving me a segmentation fault.I also tried this.

```
map<int, vector<int>> *m;
map<int, vector<int>> m1 = *m;
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(100);
m1[0] = v;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer?  It is not needed here.

Comment: Creating a pointer does not create an object of the pointed-to type. Your pointer is currently invalid; it needs to point to something before you can use it.

Comment: Your second example would work if you make `m` point to `m1`, eg: `map<int, vector<int>> m1; map<int, vector<int>> *m = &m1; ... (*m)[0] = v;`

Comment: I think i have to use a pointer because I would want to pass this map* as an argument to another function to have it modified for me. I guess using a normal map object would not do for this case.

Comment: @PranavDevarakonda you can pass a map object to the function by reference instead of by pointer. Either way will allow the function to modify the content of the map.  But you still need an actual map object for the reference/pointer to refer/point to

Comment: [This is much like the spoon in the Matrix.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAXtO5dMqEI) There is no `map`. There is only a pointer to the `map`.

Comment: `m` is a pointer to a `std::map`. But it points nowhere: you have not created an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, `m` is an **uninitialized** pointer that that not pointing at a valid `map` object.  That is why the code crashes when `m` is dereferenced to do something.

Try this instead:

```
map<int, vector<int>> m1;
map<int, vector<int>> *m = &m1;
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(100);
(*m)[0] = v;
```

Comment: Or `auto m = new std::map<int, std::vector<int>>;`. Or `auto m = std::make_unique<std::map<int, std::vector<int>>>();`

Comment: Sure, but that is not needed in this case.  You should avoid `new` if you have access to `std::make_unique()` (which didn't exist until C++14, though `std::unique_ptr` was added in C++11)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are several problems here.

Firstly you don't know how to work with pointers, so I recommend you do some reading.

Secondly you don't need to worry about pointers, as a vector or map will manage memory for you.

If you think about a vector as storing a sequence of values, and a map as providing a key for lookup, which gives you access to the value, then it's probably better if you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Are you trying to solve a problem, or just play around with pointers, vectors and maps?

There are many sources for C++ training also, but if you are using Visual Studio then you can grab working training C++ code from here and play on your local computer.
https://gitlab.com/cppocl/training/